# linux error when passing strings to functions c++

Tags: c++, linux

I am making a c++ program and I am stuck on the stage of hosting it on linux. (in fact it is an addon for node.js, but it does not matter now). I get an error when compiling my function on linux (on windows everything is OK).

```
error: cannot bind non-const lvalue reference of type ‘std::__cxx11::string&’ {aka ‘std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>&’} to an rvalue of type ‘std::__cxx11::string’ {aka ‘std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>’}
         return(merge(messUp3(a.substr(0, (int)(a.size()) / 2)), messUp3(a.substr((int)(a.size()) / 2))));
```

the problem is exactly here: `a.substr(0, (int)(a.size()) / 2)`. I have managed to fix the error by deleting & from arguments of functions. `string merge(string& a, string& b)` -> `string merge(string a, string b)`. I think I have some understanding, why it should not work with &, but then I get a complete misunderstanding of why does it work on windows? How do linux and windows gcc compilers differ? Or the problem is somewhere else?

Comment: The function messUp3 has a parameter of the referenced type std::string &. You may not bind the temporary object  created like a.substr(0, (int)(a.size()) / 2) to this reference

Comment: I understand that, but then I do not understand, why does it work on windows without any errors.

Comment: If you are compiling with the MS VS compiler then it has a bug that is called like a language extension.:)

Comment: On Windows it's probably not OK, and the compiler is too old and stupid to realize the mistake and reject it at compile time.

Comment: ah.., ok, I understood. Seems like the problem is with the compiler. I will look for an up-to-date version. Hope then it will give the error on windows too. Thanks.

Comment: On Windows, try adding `/permissive-` to the compiler command line to report this error.

Comment: Just so you know, the code would compile too if instead of removing references (&) you would declare your parameters as constant references.

Comment: @Alex I encurage you to play around with how variables can be passed around. https://godbolt.org/z/T359cf

Answer (score 0):

A reference like `std::string &` references a value that already exists as an identifiable object in memory (for example by its memory address), which is called an *lvalue* in C++ terminology.

The return value of a function is a temporary value that has not identity. The compiler is not required to allocate an address for it, which is called an *rvalue* in C++ terminology.

Thus, you cannot assign an *rvalue* to an *lvalue* reference, as the error message says.

(In fact these so-called value categories are a bit more complicated in C++.)

If you replace `std::string &` by `std::string` you create a new variable and copy the *rvalue* into it instead of referencing it, which is ok, because in this case you only read the *rvalue* instead of referencing it. (To be precise the *rvalue* will be *moved* but explaining that is beyond the scope of this answer.)

Your Windows compiler is obviously less strict with the C++ standard by creating a workaround internally instead of pointing out the error. Maybe that compiler has an option to make it more standard-conforming. I'd recommend to turn on such option, particularly if you develop for different platforms, but also to create more clean code.

Comment: Handy reading to better understand some of the terminology used: [What are rvalues, lvalues, xvalues, glvalues, and prvalues?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3601602/what-are-rvalues-lvalues-xvalues-glvalues-and-prvalues)